# Android extended LinearLayout height matches parent, but children do not

Tags: android, height, android-relativelayout, android-4.4-kitkat

I am extending a LinearLayout that is matching its parents height and width. Then inside that LinearLayout, I am inflating a view set to match parent height and width as well. The inflated views width matches the parent, but the inflated views height does not.

I have tested this on two devices, one running KitKat (API 19), in which case the problem occurs, and one running Marshmallow (API 23), in which case the problem does not occur.

This is the extended LinearLayout:

```
public class MessageBackground extends LinearLayout {

    public MessageBackground(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MessageBackground(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_background_layout, this, true);
        this.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    }

}
```

This is the inflated XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:background="#0000FF">
</RelativeLayout>
```

These are the different results I get on KitKat and Marshmallow:

[image]

I have tried several variations to try and get the xml layout to match the height of the LinearLayout on KitKat, but I can't seem to find a way to get it to work. Any suggestions or reasons why the behaviour is different would be helpful.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. is the XML code shown the message_background_layout.xml or the activity_main.xml?

Comment: The xml code shown is the message_background_layout.xml. The problem only occurs on my KitKat device, but perhaps it is device specific as opposed to KitKat specific. I will test it on a few emulators to find out.

Comment: I test on v19, v17 (Kit Kat) and v21 (Lollipop), physical devices. Doesn't show the problem. Can you have the code for the activity_main.xml (or the container of it) shown as well?

Comment: It is inside of a list view and I think this is part of the problem. I am trying to recreate that issue on a very simplified activity, and once I do I will post it here. Thank you for your help so far.